# Why is the body background in my website not showing up?

Tags: html, css

The website is http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/.

Here is the link for the image of the design so you could see the difference.
http://i52.tinypic.com/de6yja.png

In the body, you can see a little portion of gray(which is actually part of the header image), but the rest of the body is white. Please help.

Also I have used a lot of CSS3 properties in the website, and have used the IE7-js to make IE-6 to IE-8 render it like IE9, but it doesnt seem to be working. Is there some other script or a newer method to do it?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div #header (http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/style.css) should be larger. Change 570px to 670px

```
#header (line 46)

{

**height: 570px;**
background-color: #540451;
background-image: url("images/header.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center top;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto auto;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;

}
```

Cheers

Comment: aww. Thanks Alot ! Silly Me... That did solve the background problem.